# Unable to start blueprint due to unresolved dependencies

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, blueprint-osgi, spring-camel

I'm new to camel and blueprint. trying to install my application in Jboss fuse but I get an error -

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:343)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_80]
2019-10-15 20:27:53,467 | ERROR | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 23 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.5 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle error-handler/2.6 due to unresolved dependencies [(objectClass=com.wired.gps.GpsData)]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:343)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_80]
```

Can anyone please help in this, when do we get unresolved dependency error and it shows as component = velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

installed camel-velocity bundle and it worked